# How to get contact change notification with contacts details

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to get notified contact change with contact details.

Through ContactObserver , I can get notifications when ever contacts are getting changed Or updated.

But my intention is to get the exact contact id of the changed contact .

As an alternative -

Right now , I am storing contact details in my own db and whenever contact change notification comes , I do compare both the contact lists to find the out the odd one.

I know this is a poor way to fulfil my objective.

Are there any other efficient ways to achieve this ?

Even I have used the new apis of ContentObserver ( V16 )

```
  @Override
  public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
   //still the uri is not useful to detect changed contact
  }
```